# Oracle Apex 18.1 Interactive Grid (IG) Setting filters programmatically? Customizing IG Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, plsql, oracle-apex

Is there a way to set filters for an IG in Oracle Apex via an Javascript or PL/SQL API?

Doing my research i stumbled across [APEX IG Cookbook for 5.1.4](http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2018/01/01/apex-ig-cookbook-for-5-1-4/)
or some Blogposts [How to hack APEX interactive grid series](http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/18/how-to-hack-apex-interactive-grid-part-1/) for customizing IGs with Javascript. So setting filters similar to the [PL/SQL APEX_IR.ADD_FILTER Proceedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/ADD_FILTER-Procedure-Signature-2.htm#AEAPI29344) where you can set filters for an interactive Report (IR) the column name, operator and filter value
should be possible.

I figured out the name of the internal tables, where the filters are stored if they're set (APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IR_COND for IR Filters and APEX_APPL_PAGE_IG_RPT_FILTERS for IG) but don't really know if that's helpful.

With 
`apex.region("StaticRegionID").widget().toolbar("findElement","search_field").val("SearchTextValue");
apex.region("StaticRegionID").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("search");`
 
it is possible to set the Searchvalue and execute the search action but it isn't possible to set the operator/Filter type (EQ, NEQ, LT, LTE, GT,GTE, LIKE, NLIKE, N, NN, C, NC, IN, NIN)

So far i haven't found a good way to customize the search action in `libaries\apex\widget.interactiveGrid.js` or to set the right parameter before invoking the search action in order to add the filters.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved my problem. There is an Method called `addFilter` inside the `libaries\apex\widget.interactiveGrid.js` which can be simply called with a filter object and a options object as parameter. 
This is really useful when combined with the values from other Inputfields.

Example:

```js
apex.region("YourStaticRegionID").widget().interactiveGrid("addFilter", {
  type: 'column',
  columnType: 'column',
  columnName: 'YourColumnName',
  operator: 'EQ',
  value: $v2('P2_NEW'),
  isCaseSensitive: false
});
```

The [$v2 API](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/Non-namespace-Javascript-APIs.htm#AEAPI-GUID-DEF1383A-C2A6-4B5D-826D-36D78E85F5F8) is used in the example above to get the search term the user typed in a Text Input Field called P2_NEW.

Comment: Please also mention where we need to put this code ?

Comment: @Rams This is normal javascript code.
I've put this code inside a dynamic action which is triggered whenever I press a specific button or press a specific key.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to modify it to search two columns for the value instead of one. Or just set it to search everywhere.

Comment: Try calling the function twice. I think the filters are additive as long as you don't remove a filter for a column manually or programmatically. @TineO

Comment: Im sorry, i wasnt clear. I want the value to be in either of the two columns. If it had to be in both columns, calling it twice would certainly work.

Comment: @TineO As far as I know the filters only stack. There's always an AND condition between them. In Theory you should also be able to place an OR condition but so far I haven't found the right place in the code and have no clue how to implement it. I'm sorry. Maybe some of the oracle guys have ideas.

Comment: Ended up just duplicating all items, buttons and Dynamic actions, so now it works.