# Programmatically add regular expression filter to Oracle Apex Interactive report

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I am filtering an interactive report (IR) with values from Page items. Filters are applied with the APEX_IR.ADD_FILTER (API).
I'm stuck trying to programmatically add a regular expression filter to IR.

The report within the application has that option (Actions>Filter>operator 'matches regular expression') but the API does not seem to support REGEXP operator (only: EQ, NEQ, LT, LTE, GT,GTE, LIKE, NLIKE, N, NN, C, NC, IN, NIN).

I have a couple of questions:

1. Why doesn't the API support the REGEXP operator? Could it ever in the future?
2. What are my options?

About question 2; I can filter my results in my IR SQL query but I'd really like to also see that filter so the user knows what is being filtered in the background. 
I can probably use javascript to inject HTML code that creates that filter element (everything that goes along with it) and simply fake the filter (real filtering is in the SQL query) but that's my last resort.

Also, I'm not opening the IR page from another page so I can't use IR_ROWFILTER as a page parameter and just transfer and apply the regular expression that way.

Third question comes to mind now - can I fake the IR so it thinks I'm calling it with a IR_ROWFILTER parameter?

I'm working on Apex 18.1.

---

Workaround: For now, romeuBraga's proposal to work with an Interactive Grid seems to be a good enough workaround. IG, through javascript API, accepts REGEXP operator.

Comment: I can't found a way to filter IR with a regular expression. But that is possible in a interactive grid. You can disable the edit functionality and it will looks like a interactive report... Take a look in that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696987/oracle-apex-18-1-interactive-grid-ig-setting-filters-programmatically-customi/51704962 . To filter with a regular expression, the parameter is "REGEXP".

Comment: Thank you romeuBraga. I saw that post but I figured the operator's list is the same (without REGEXP). I suppose the IG is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, but I tested "regexp" here and works...

Comment: Yes yes, I agree. REGEXP works programmatically with an IG and that seems like a good enough workaround.