# IG clear filters and set new ones

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am setting up a page in APEX 18.2 and it contains an IG. I can get to this page normaly from the menu, or I have it set up to go here from a different site if a button is pressed. If that button is pressed a hidden item on the first site is also set to a value, and I would like to clear all current filters and set a new filter for that value being in one of two columns.

I have checked out everything I could find online about it but the official JSDoc has nothing about the methods needed and other sources did not contain exactly what I need.

[Oracle Apex 18.1 Interactive Grid (IG) Setting filters programmatically? Customizing IG Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696987/oracle-apex-18-1-interactive-grid-ig-setting-filters-programmatically-customi) 
This was by far the best resource I had for setting the filter, but it only filters on one column, the first method he described didnt work for me, gave an error.

I also found some code to clear the filter, but what it does is actually resets the report, which would work for me, if it actually worked, but half the time it triggers errors. Actually got ORA-2291 which I have no idea what its about. I also sometimes just get no data found

The code I use to set a filter is basically the same from the first link:

```
apex.region("MY_IG").widget().interactiveGrid("addFilter", {
  type: 'column',
  columnType: 'column',
  columnName: 'COLUMN_NAME',
  operator: 'C',
  value: $v2('PAGE_ITEM'),
  isCaseSensitive: false
});
```

But this applies the filter to a single column. I would like to set it to two columns, or just everywhere if thats not possible.

The code I use to clear filters/reset the report:

```
 apex.region("MY_IG").call("getActions").invoke('reset-report');
```

I want the Dynamic action that triggers these blocks of code to clear all filters and set up a new one that evaluates if the value in the PAGE_ITEM is contained in either of two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didnt actually find how to do what I wanted, but did something different to get the same result.

Ended up just replacing all this with a WHERE clause in my SQL query.